# Wordpress migration - MySQL guid column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a slight problem with a wordpress migration. I've bulk uploaded posts from csv on my local WAMP server as it's faster and then uploaded & imported a SQL dump to the remote server.

In the `guid` column of the `wp_posts` table, it contains the url of the post - I presume (might be wrong, please correct if I am) this is the same as the 'permalink' setting when you edit a post - and all of them are `http://localhost/post-name/` which is fine for now, I'm happy to work on an SQL query to replace if needed.

I've uploaded the SQL dump and it still shows '`http://localhost/post-name`' in the remote server db as expected. However when I search for a post on the frontend, just to make sure it's picking up the posts OK, I was expecting the links to give me a 404 error until I changed the links, but they don't - they point nicely to the `http://remoteserver.com/post-name/`

Where as it's a nice problem to have as it still works - I was wondering why & do I need to change it? I prefer to not mess with the db if at all possible.

Comment: Are you able to login from admin side

Answer (score 0):

When migrating, you might need to define your wordpress url in wp-config.php, and I recommend find and replacing the database with [this tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). It's pretty neat, because it pre-populates your database from your config file. Obviously, you'd replace `http://localhost/` with `http://www.yoursite.com/`

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already got that tool installed on the local server - going to backup & have a go locally & when I've got my head around it then I'll have a go on the remote. What I can't get my head around is though, why it's working on the remote even though I haven't changed any of those guid entries yet - they still point to localhost